# Delete a file that was created with fallocate

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, swap

I started to create a swapfile. I used this command:

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
```

Then, I decided that I want to make the swapfile in a different path, so I used the command again with the right path and activated the new swap file.

How can I delete the first file that I created?

Comment: Personally, I prefer a logical volume (or partition) based paging space, or none at all. A useful example of fallocate in any case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fallocate` just creates a file, it does nothing specific to swap, so you can simply `rm /swapfile`.

If you had turned it into a swapfile with `mkswap` then `swapon` you can simply use `swapoff /swapfile` to stop your machine using it as swap.